# Animate single element on background

Tags: css, background, jpeg, animated

What would be the most efficient way to change the walk signals on the header image on http://www.danielLmusic.com from red to green. I would think there'd be a more efficient way to do it than to change backgrounds since i'm only changing a small percentage of it. Any help for my newbie self would be most appreciated.Also, it's a wordpress site if that makes any difference.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please include your markup, CSS and if possible a JSFiddle. Most people here won't want to visit your site to fix the problem. Thanks!

Comment: The easy way would be to have a separate image (or create an image sprite) that has the green light and then toggle between them

Answer (score 2):

Recreated the background image so that the signals are TRANSPARENT, you'll need to use a PNG or GIF. Use background-color CSS property to change the color, leaving the background-image untouched.

```
.bg {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url('...');
}
.bg:hover {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: That's smart.  That's real smart.

Comment: This is a fantastic approach, hey I might steal this ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. The only problem I foresee with that is that it would turn both the walk and stop signal green or red. Is there some workaround to that perhaps? Thanks again

Comment: @user2661937 - There are plenty of work arounds, you could for instance, absolute position DIV elements under your transparent parts and change those background colors. Or, just use DIVs with border-radius so they are circles and use them for your colored signals.

Comment: @LastCoder , I assume I can do this with images, too? I'm pretty new to web programming. The thing that complicates this a little for me also is that I am using a premium wordpress theme. I figured the best way to go about this (since I have to create new div elements) is to create a child theme. Once I have the divss in place, what would be the best way to fade in between the red and green, or make them blink? Thanks in advance, again.

Comment: @user2661937 - look-up the CSS "transition" property, if you us that when you change the ex: background-color it will fade from the current color to the new color. You could also use a CSS animation to create a blinking effect.